# GSON serialization fails with custom Objects

Tags: java, javafx, gson

I have the following class

```
public class Strassennetz {

    private ObservableMap<Position, Strassenabschnitt> abschnitte;
    private Map<Position, List<Auto>> autos;
    private SimpleListProperty<Auto> autoList;
    private BooleanProperty simuliert;
    private String name;
    public static Strassennetz instance;
    
    ...
}
```

which I want to serialize and deserialize with **GSON/FxGson:**

```
Gson gsonBuilder = FxGson.coreBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(Strassenabschnitt.class, StrassenAdapter.getInstance())
                .enableComplexMapKeySerialization()
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                .create();
        String jsonResult = gsonBuilder.toJson(instance);
```

The StrassenAdapter was necessary to (de-)serialize the abstract class Strassenabschnitt correctly.
That serialization works as expected when I set the fields "autos" and "autoList" transient.
As soon as I want to include those fields in my serialization (which is very important), I get the following exception:

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class
> com.sun.javafx.util.WeakReferenceQueue$ListEntry declares multiple
> JSON fields named next

The class Auto looks like that:

```
public class Auto {

    public enum AutoModell {ROT, POLIZEI, BLAU}

    private int geschwindigkeit;
    private static final int MAXGESCHWINDIGKEIT = 8;
    private SimpleObjectProperty<Himmelsrichtung> richtung = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    private Queue<Wendepunkt> wendepunkte;

    private SimpleIntegerProperty positionX;
    private SimpleIntegerProperty positionY;
    private int breite;
    private int laenge;
    private AutoModell autoModell;
    private final transient Strassennetz strassennetz;
    private Rectangle rectangle;
    
    ...
}
```

I went through three google search result pages looking for an answer, but I do not get it to work.

Comment: I think you may have to post the full versions of the classes you are attempting to serialize but in the meantime if you did not find this then please refer to : https://www.reddit.com/r/javahelp/comments/ge4xzm/problem_using_gson_286/ and more especially where it is stated "is unlikely to serialize to JSON. It's not a simple data class; it has methods declared that can confuse the GSON serializer."

Comment: GSON serializes objects by actually serializing the *fields* instead of the *properties*: i.e. it uses reflection to get the values of the (private) instance variables, instead of accessing the values via get/set methods. In the case of your JavaFX properties, this can become problematic, as it may end up trying to serialize, for example, listeners registered with those properties. I don't use GSON much (actually primarily for this reason), but there may be a way to tell it to use "property access". Otherwise, the Jackson libraries use get/set methods by default.

Comment: @James_D but I can somehow serialize with that method without the Map autos and the list autoList. Jackson had a lot problems with JavaFX properties. GSON and FxGson handled it very well.

Comment: @fusion Hmm: strange. Anything should handle basic collections easily.

Comment: @James_D yeah basic collections do work. But Jackson struggles with FX properties whereas GSON works. Except for that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to put Rectangle (in my Auto-class) as a transient variable. FxGson can handle JavaFX-Properties, but not Shape instances. So I ignored that field on serialization and made sure, that I initialized that field on another way.

Answer (score 0):

GSON really does not play nicely with JavaFX properties, because it fails to properly respect encapsulation. The default way GSON serializes and object is to use reflection to recursively get the values of *fields*, rather than getting values of *properties* (as defined by get/set methods).

In a JavaFX application, JavaFX properties are typically used in the data model to implement "enhanced java beans" (where the enhancement is the ability to register listeners with the properties, etc.)

Consider a typical JavaFX bean-type class:

```
public class Item {
    
    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final IntegerProperty value = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    
    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name ;
    }
    
    public final String getName() {
        return nameProperty().get();
    }
    
    public final void setName(String name) {
        nameProperty().set(name);
    }
    
    public IntegerProperty valueProperty() {
        return value ;
    }
    
    public final int getValue() {
        return valueProperty().get() ;
    }
    
    public final void setValue(int value) {
        valueProperty().set(value);
    }
}
```

If you imagine serializing instances of this class "by hand", you would not be interested in the internal implementation of the `name` and `value` properties, or any listeners registered on those properties; you would be only interested in serializing the *values* represented by the properties (i.e. the values returned by `getName()` and `getValue()`). To deserialize an `Item` instance, you would simply instantiate an `Item`, and call `setName()` and `setValue()` with the serialized values.

If you try using GSON "as-is" to serialize, say, a list of such `Item` instances:

```
public class App  {



    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        Random rng = new Random();
        rng.setSeed(42);
        
        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; i++) {
            Item item = new Item();
            item.setName("Item "+i);
            item.setValue(rng.nextInt(100));
            item.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println(newValue));
            items.add(item);
        }
        
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        String gsonJson = gson.toJson(items);
        System.out.println(gsonJson);
        

    }

}
```

You get the following:

```
[
  {
    "name": {
      "name": "",
      "value": "Item 1",
      "valid": false
    },
    "value": {
      "name": "",
      "value": 30,
      "valid": true,
      "helper": {
        "observable": {}
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "name": {
      "name": "",
      "value": "Item 2",
      "valid": false
    },
    "value": {
      "name": "",
      "value": 63,
      "valid": true,
      "helper": {
        "observable": {}
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "name": {
      "name": "",
      "value": "Item 3",
      "valid": false
    },
    "value": {
      "name": "",
      "value": 48,
      "valid": true,
      "helper": {
        "observable": {}
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "name": {
      "name": "",
      "value": "Item 4",
      "valid": false
    },
    "value": {
      "name": "",
      "value": 84,
      "valid": true,
      "helper": {
        "observable": {}
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "name": {
      "name": "",
      "value": "Item 5",
      "valid": false
    },
    "value": {
      "name": "",
      "value": 70,
      "valid": true,
      "helper": {
        "observable": {}
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Notice how the internal elements of the `StringProperty` and `IntegerProperty` are serialized, including the listeners, which are almost certainly irrelevant to the data that you want to persist or transmit.

In your exception, you see the serialization of the listeners causing an exception (somewhere it appears you have a binding or an explicit weak listener registered on one or more of the properties: the weak listener cannot be serialized).

Worse, this cannot be deserialized:

```
List<Item> itemsFromGson = gson.fromJson(gsonJson, new TypeToken<List<Item>>() {}.getType());
```

generates an exception, because `StringProperty` and `IntegerProperty` cannot be constructed.

One solution here is to define custom serializers and deserializers for the `StringProperty` and `IntegerProperty` (and other `Property`) classes, which simply serialize and deserialize the contained value:

```
public class App  {



    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        Random rng = new Random();
        rng.setSeed(42);
        
        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; i++) {
            Item item = new Item();
            item.setName("Item "+i);
            item.valueProperty().set(rng.nextInt(100));
            item.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println(newValue));
            items.add(item);
        }
        
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(StringProperty.class, new JsonSerializer<StringProperty>() {

            @Override
            public JsonElement serialize(StringProperty src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
                
                return new JsonPrimitive(src.get());
            }
            
        });
        
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(StringProperty.class, new JsonDeserializer<StringProperty>() {

            @Override
            public StringProperty deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) {
                
                return new SimpleStringProperty(json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString());
            }
            
        });
        
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(IntegerProperty.class, new JsonSerializer<IntegerProperty>() {

            @Override
            public JsonElement serialize(IntegerProperty src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
                
                return new JsonPrimitive(src.get());
            }
            
        });
        
        
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(IntegerProperty.class, new JsonDeserializer<IntegerProperty>() {

            @Override
            public IntegerProperty deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) {
                
                return new SimpleIntegerProperty(json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsInt());
            }
            
        });
        
        
        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.setPrettyPrinting().create();
        
        
        String gsonJson = gson.toJson(items);
        System.out.println(gsonJson);
        

        System.out.println("\n================\n");
        
        List<Item> itemsFromGson = gson.fromJson(gsonJson, new TypeToken<List<Item>>() {}.getType());
        System.out.println(itemsFromGson);
    }
}
```

This version generates the expected

```js
[
  {
    "name": "Item 1",
    "value": 30
  },
  {
    "name": "Item 2",
    "value": 63
  },
  {
    "name": "Item 3",
    "value": 48
  },
  {
    "name": "Item 4",
    "value": 84
  },
  {
    "name": "Item 5",
    "value": 70
  }
]
```

It's perhaps worth noting that the Jackson serialization libraries, by default, use "property access", i.e. they use `get` and `set` methods to serialize and deserialize the fields. Consequently, Jackson works very nicely with bean classes that follow the standard JavaFX Property pattern (like the `Item` class above) *as long as the properties are all read/write* (i.e. they have corresponding `get` and `set` methods); extra work is needed for read-only properties.

Comment: Thanks for that extensive answer. But as I already mentioned, I do not use the Gson standard builder. I use FxGson, which handles JavaFX Properties pretty good and they (de-)serialize without problems.